# How do I specify how many byte the opencv imwrite function writes to an image?

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, opencv

I have a numpy array and would like to save this as pgm image. This works, but how can i specify if it is witten to 8 Bit or a 16 Bit image

The command I use is: `cv.imwrite("img.pgm", numpy_array)`,
cv is OpenCV

I would like to write a 8,16 or 64 Bit grayscale image. Now I just save an image but I do not know, how many bits are written.

There is also this command:

```
compression_rate = 0
cv.imwrite("/path_image.pgm", image, [cv.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, compression_rate])
```

which specifies a compression rate, but I don't really know what does that do. I also checked the documentation: [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html)

Thanks

Comment: You could convert the image to the desired bit before writing it. Most images are default `uint8`. To convert to `uint16` you can do `image = np.uint16(image)` and for `uint64` you can do `image = np.uint64(image)`

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to find out what data type/format your image is being written as? [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) is some reading material on data types in numpy, it might come in handy.